# Fedex API schedule pickkup

Tags: php, api, fedex

I am developing a web plugin.

I have a FedEx API `$key`, `$userid`, `$password` and `$meter`

### My plugin target:

- I have a website from where user will be register and add FedEx Account number in his account(my website user account section)
- When user added his own FedEx Account number then he will able to create FedEx schedule pickup on behalf of his FedEx Account number.(FedEx Account number will be different-2 for every user)

### My Question:

- Can we develop such type of functionality with FedEx.
- can we able to create schedule pickup with different -2 FedEx Account number
- My Developer `$key`, `$userid`, `$password` and `$meter` will be same for every user or we require different -2 Developer `$key`, `$userid`, `$password` and `$meter` for every FedEx Account Number.

Please suggest me solution for this or share some link and document.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer you step by step.

**Can we develop such type of functionality with FedEx.**

Yes, you can use fedex webserbice to create shipping label and so have shipment ready to be picked up, or as well you can request a pickup by using a specific call, which is **Courrier Dispatch**. From documentation:

```
Category            Service                                     Description
Shipping            Ship/Cancel Ship                            Obtain a label for your package

Courier Dispatch    Courier Dispatch/Cancel Courier Dispatch    Request Courier pick up
```

**can we able to create schedule pickup with different -2 FedEx Account number:**

You can create as many pickup as you want with many account as you are `allowed to use.`

**My Developer $key, $userid, $password and $meter will be same for every user or we require different -2 Developer $key, $userid, $password and $meter for every FedEx Account Number.**

As all webservice, once you log with your with your params to your account the all operation will be done with your account, so they will be correlated to your account only. As you know, once you register to gain api authorization you start by identify yourself with your account number, so all operations with your token will be done by your account. I really think you will need to have authorization parameters for each customer you would like to request a pickup. You might get in touch with them to ask if they have a way to do such interactions between your auth params and other accounts number. I think the faster solution, if possible, would be to charge your customer for pickup and request by your account.

**you can find fedex documentation here** http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/solutions.html